# The best and shortest way to call a jws void method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, soap

If I'm not expecting to get a result back (void method) what's the shortest and best way to call a soap jws web-service's method using JavaScript ?

Answer (score 0):

This is tested and it works (you'll need jQuery)

code :

```
$.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "http://localhost:****/webservicedirectory/webservice.jws",
                data: 'method=methodname&variable1=value1&variable2=value2&.......&variablen=valuen',
                success: function() {},
                error: function() {}
            });
```

**** : port number

**ps :** leave error and success empty because it might return error even if it works